# prefix and postfix operators c++

Tags: c++, operators, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

```
class compl{
    float re,im;

public:
    compl(float r, float i)
        {re=r; im=i;}
    compl& operator++()
        {++re; return*this;} //(1)
    compl operator++(int k){
        compl z=*this; re++; im+=k; return z;} //(2)
    friend compl& operator--(compl& z)
        {--z.re; return z;}
    friend compl operator--(compl& z,int k)
        {compl x=z; z.re--; z.im-=k; return x;}
};
```

(1) Why do we have to return current object by reference? As I understood, reference is just a second name for something.

(2) Why do we have to save current object in z, then change the object and return the unchanged z? Doing this, we are returning the value that is not increased. Is it because of the way that postfix operator works(it returns the old value, and then increases it)

Comment: 1. operator chaining 2. *post* increment

Comment: I would ask why did you make the postfix operators `friend`s? They are perfect candidates for member functions.

Comment: It's an example from the book. Is it better to write them as member functions because they change the value of parameters?

Comment: @KiokoKey I see no reason to `friend` them. They are tightly related to your object, so they should be member functions. In general you `friend` a somewhat decoupled function that you need to gave access to your private/protected members, such as e.g. `operator<<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You don't have to, but it's idiomatic because it allows for chaining operators or calls.

(2) Yes, postfix should return the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

1- Operator ++ overloading must return by reference but if you don't need an alias for the variable you can add a function called next or anything like that with the same structure.

2- Yes, as you need to return current value then increment the variable.

Answer (score -2):

(1) because we want ++ to return a value too, as in

```
a = b++;
```

and it costs less than returning a copy.

(2) yes, it is the way the postfix operator work. This explains why it is generally recommended to write a loop with iterators using prefix incrementation

```
for(iterator it = ..... ; it != .... , ++it) { ...}
```

instead of postfix incrementation: it avoids building a temporary copy.

Comment: (1) is not correct, OP was asking why prefix `operator++` must return a reference.

Comment: 1) it musts return some value so we can use it in an assignment. Which leaves only two possibilities
- by value
- by reference
2) return by value costs more - and also doesn't work if the incremented is transmitted as a parameter to a function (by reference).

Comment: Agree, but your explanation of (1) is not correct. First, you have a postfix there. Second, `a = ++b` will still make a copy, even if `++b` returns a reference (unless of course `a` is a reference). The situation where it is indeed useful is in assignments like `++b = something`.